# ruby split 2 chars from an array of 4 chars

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

i have an 4 characters array = ["0222"]
Need to split in 2 groups of 2 each

Need to get array = ["02","22"]
Try split, but can´t get the result i need.

Comment: Is there any reason your 4-character string is wrapped in an array? Could the array contain more than one string? If so, what would be the expected result? And what about strings containing less than or more than 4 characters?

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing and inaccurate.  What you actually have is an array with a single element.  That single element is a 4 character string.  What you really need to do is access and split that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few other options to play with:

Using `String#[]`:

```
array_1 = ["0222"]
array_2 = [array_1[0][0..1], array_1[0][2..-1]]  #=>  ["02", "22"]
array_2 = [array_1[0][0, 2], array_1[0][2, 2]]  #=>  ["02", "22"]
```

Using `String#split` (in this example along with a regex, a capture group, a look-behind, and a limit):

```
array_1 = ["0222"]
array_2 = array_1[0].split(/(?<=\d{2})/, 2)
#=>  ["02", "22"]
```

Using `String#partition` (in this example along with the `Array#drop` method to creatively split the string at a specific location and then only keep that match along with the remaining element):

```
array_1 = ["0222"]
array_2 = array_1[0].partition(/.{2}/).drop(1)
#=>  ["02", "22"]
```

Using `String#split` along with `String#insert` to force a split at a specific location:

```
array_1 = ["0222"]
array_2 = array_1[0].insert(2, " ").split
#=>  ["02", "22"]
```

Or maybe even using `String#split` and a regex along with `Array#[]` like this:

```
array_1 = ["0222"]
array_2 = array_1[0].split(/^(..)/)[1, 2]
#=>  ["02", "22"]
```

Lots and lots of potential solutions that could be used in any number of combinations.  I do however think the best solution is to use the `String#scan` method as already mentioned by @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing a regex match all on the pattern `\d{1,2}`:

```
nums = "0222".scan(/\d{1,2}/)
puts nums
```

This prints:

```
02
22
```

Comment: When inspecting objects you might want to use [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#p-method) which would print `["02", "22"]` here.